# Understand exponent in python quantize method

Tags: python, decimal

I am not a math guy, so I am struggling to understand the difference below:

```
>>> Decimal(1.144).quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
Decimal('1.14')
>>> Decimal(1.144).quantize(Decimal('0.00'))
Decimal('1.14')
>>> Decimal(1.145).quantize(Decimal('0.00'))
Decimal('1.15')
>>> Decimal(1.145).quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
Decimal('1.15')
```

So what's the difference having `0.00` vs `0.01` in exponent value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely nothing. Neither the sign nor the coefficient digits are examined by the `quantize()` method.

Comment: Rats!  You got there 10 sec. sooner!

Comment: what about `1.00` or `10.00` ??

Comment: Those two values only differ in coefficient digits.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.  Only the exponent (the number of decimal places, effectively) from the first argument is used.